# Why is a video created by FFmpeg from static image is rejected by YouTube?

Tags: ffmpeg, javascript, youtube, node.js, npm

I am trying to input a `image.jpg` file and audio file.

I need output as video of 1080p quality.

Recently I tried the command given in ffmpeg doc Encode/YouTube and got the output.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i image.jpg -i input.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a copy -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

But that video when I am trying to upload on YouTube says: “Video from the camera roll not supported.”

Can anyone suggest me the command.

[ffprobe vide.mp4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNsC4.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to make a video out of a static image and an audio file?

Comment: yes it is a image.jpg file and input.mp3 or input.wav file i can use any audio format.

Comment: Does the video play locally for you before trying to upload it to YouTube?

Comment: yes it play well

Comment: Hmmm... For the most part, I don't use Google products (YouTube is owned by Google), so I can't help you with that end, but hopefully the answers to my questions will enable someone else to help you more quickly.  I hope you find the help you desire.

Comment: How are you uploading the video? Have you searched that error to see what it might indicate? Why did you tag this node.js, Javascript, and npm?

Comment: I suppose the "video from camera roll" may just mean the video is saved in the Camera Roll folder and that's where you're uploading it from. What format is the video? What command are you using to create it? Please use the EDIT button and improve and clarify your question.

Comment: That error comes when we upload video which is recorded from camera with no ai.

Comment: I edited the command i used above.

Comment: Can you add `ffprobe <videofile>` output to the question? For us to know what properties your resulted video file has. (This is actually more informative than command line used do produce it.) Maybe someone will be able to spot a clue.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov added ffprobe vide.mp4 output in question.

Comment: I found why it says that. everything is fine but problem is in -c:v copy. when i am using -c:v acc it is not showing error but the problem is that duration of the video is wrong

Comment: Does Youtube ever support fps=2?